# require and import not working for node libraries in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, import, require

So I am trying to import a nodejs library `net` into a vuejs project. But I cannot import the library. I have tried using `const net = require('net')`, `const net = require('net').default`, and `import * as net from 'net'` however none of these work and the object is empty (if i console.log() it, or throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createServer' of undefined`. I have also tried using both `yarn` and `npm` with no luck.

The `net` module is definitely in my `node_modules/` folder.

Component file

```html
<template>
    <p>charts placeholder</p>
</template>

<script>
    const net = require('net').default;
    console.log(net);
    const port = 8080;
    const host = '127.0.0.1';

    let server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
        socket.on('data', function(data){
            let str = data.toString();
            console.log(str);
            try {
                let json = JSON.parse(str);
                console.log(json);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('error str: ' + str);
            }

        });
        socket.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
    });

    server.listen(port, host);


    export default {
        name: "Charts"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Any advice would be great thanks.

Comment: Did you do `npm install net`?

Comment: Yup I had definitely installed it. The problem was associated with my project, I created a new project and I was able to import modules without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the point of the frontend framework. If you want to make data available to your Vue application, you should use a separate project and run them separately.

To exchange data between your frontend and backend you can use axios or others: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html#ad